# How do you extract distinct elements from a list?

Tags: f#

I'm pretty new to f# and I'm having a hard time trying to extract a list of distinct values from a list:

```
let myList = [ 1; 2; 2; 3; 4; 3 ]
// desired list
[ 1; 2; 3; 4 ]
```

How do I do that? I see that `seq` has a `distinct` method, but not lists.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
let myList = [ 1; 2; 2; 3; 4; 3 ]
let distinctList = myList |> Seq.distinct |> List.ofSeq
```

Result:

```
> 
val myList : int list = [1; 2; 2; 3; 4; 3]
val distinctList : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4]
```

Next F# version (4.0) will have `List.distinct` function

Comment: I'm a little confused by this code (which works great). So you can pass a list to Seq.distinct? ...no wait... is this because list implements seq (er..whatever the functional term is)?

Comment: Sequences in F# are represented by the `seq<'T>` type, which is an alias for `IEnumerable`. List implements `IEnumerable` so you can call all `Seq` module functions on it. But if you need List as a result you have to transform resulting `seq` back to list using `List.ofSeq` function.

Comment: I am using F# 4.0 and there is no `List.distinct`. Doesn't using `Seq` cause lazy evaluation? Or perhaps it is forced by `List.ofSeq` (which I guess would be equivalent to using `Seq.toList` here).

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if worse or better than [Petr answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30633274/4925216) but you could also do :

```
let distinct xs = xs |> Set.ofList |> Set.toList

> distinct [ 1; 2; 2; 3; 4; 3 ];;
val it : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4]
```